# Есть ли возможность с помощью Zabbix мониторить usb устройства, в частности вставлена или нет флешка?

Tags: zabbix

Нужно мониторить на удаленных системах была ли вставлена флешка или нет, пал выбор на заббих, но пока-что не смог найти варианта для этого на нем

Comment: Это разве не оно? system.hw.devices[usb] :https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/hosts/inventory

Comment: При условии, что на эту _удаленную систему_ вы предварительно можете поставит zabbix-agent.